# in knockout can I get the name of the observables

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

just wondering in knockout is there a way to get the name of the models observables?

in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/1/

I have a an observable array that I am using to create a table. and I have an array used to store the table headers.  is there a way to just get the table headers from the products object itself and not have to have a separate array to store the table headers? as in just get name, price, and tags from the model itself somehow?

```
function Product(name, price, tags) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.price = ko.observable(price);
  tags = typeof(tags) !== 'undefined' ? tags : [];
  this.tags = ko.observableArray(tags);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.shoppingCart = ko.observableArray("");
  this.headers = ["name", "price", "tags"];
};

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  myViewModel.shoppingCart.push(
     new Product("Buns", 1.49, ['Baked goods', 'Hot dogs']),
     new Product("Cups", 2.00, ['Paper Products', 'Drinks']),
     new Product("Plates", 1.50, ['Paper Products'])
  );

});
```

and here is the html table.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr data-bind='foreach: headers'>
    <th data-bind='text: $data'></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody data-bind='foreach: shoppingCart'>
    <tr>
      <td data-bind='text: name'></td>
      <td data-bind='text: price'></td>
      <td>
        <!-- Add a list of tags. -->
        <ul data-bind='foreach: tags'>
          <li data-bind='text: $data'></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Can you explain a bit more about what you want? A different data structure?

Comment: just thought putting the name of the headers (name, price, tags) in a separate array to print them as the header values in the table was a bit redundant. just wondering if I could get name, price, tags from the model somehow.  for example I think angular has something like {{key}}. to do something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to extract the observable properties

```
function Product(name, price, tags) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.price = ko.observable(price);
  tags = typeof(tags) !== 'undefined' ? tags : [];
  this.tags = ko.observableArray(tags);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.shoppingCart = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.headers = ko.observableArray([]);
};

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  myViewModel.shoppingCart.push(
     new Product("Buns", 1.49, ['Baked goods', 'Hot dogs']),
     new Product("Cups", 2.00, ['Paper Products', 'Drinks']),
     new Product("Plates", 1.50, ['Paper Products'])
  );
  var product = myViewModel.shoppingCart()[0];
  for (var key in product) {
    if (product.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        myViewModel.headers.push(key);
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/t2f43qov/7/

ps - you might want to change the field names to `this.Name` etc or just make the first letter of the key capitalized before you push it

Comment: If you do a lot of similar stuff, make it a function that subscribes to the shoppingCart etc observableArray (s).  Then you can update headings even if the titles change

Comment: Note: you can also use `Object.keys()` on a reasonably modern browser.
https://jsfiddle.net/t2f43qov/8/

Comment: Yes, I tend not to because KO supports back to IE 6, but every project has its own target audience